# How to add secondary sequential numbering to elements dragged in to a hierarchy tree node using jstree?

Tags: r, shiny, drag-and-drop, jstree, jstreer

I am trying to add secondary sequential numbering to elements dragged in to a hierarchy tree node, using the package jsTreeR, as shown in the illustration at the bottom. Below is the reproducible code used for the illustration. This sequential numbering (via letters not numbers) represents the number of times a particular element was dragged into the target node.

Any ideas for how to do this?

Note that in a related post, [In R Shiny how to append to each list element the sequential number of times it appears in the list using sortable js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72477622/in-r-shiny-how-to-append-to-each-list-element-the-sequential-number-of-times-it), the same issue was addressed but using HTML/CSS with the sortable package instead.

Reproducible code:

```
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Menu",
    state = list(opened = TRUE),
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "Mickey",
        type = "moveable",
        state = list(disabled = TRUE)
      ),
      list(
        text = "Mouse",
        type = "moveable",
        state = list(disabled = TRUE)
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = ">>> Drag here <<<",
    type = "target",
    state = list(opened = TRUE)
    )
)

checkCallback <- JS(
  "function(operation, node, parent, position, more) { ",
  "  if(operation === 'copy_node') {",
  "    if(parent.id === '#' || node.parent !== 'j1_1' || parent.type !== 'target') {",
  "      return false;", # prevent moving an item above or below the root
  "    }",               # and moving inside an item except a 'target' item
  "  }",
  "  if(operation === 'delete_node') {",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('deletion', position + 1);",
  "  }",
  "  return true;",      # allow everything else
  "}"
)

dnd <- list(
  always_copy = TRUE,
  # inside_pos = "last",
  is_draggable = JS(
    "function(node) {",
    "  return node[0].type === 'moveable';",
    "}"
  )
)

mytree <- jstree(
  nodes, dragAndDrop = TRUE, dnd = dnd, checkCallback = checkCallback,
  types = list(moveable = list(), target = list())
)

script <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mytree").on("copy_node.jstree", function(e, data){
    var instance = data.new_instance;
    var node = data.node;
    var id = node.id;
    var index = $("#"+id).index() + 1;
    var text = index + ". " + node.text;
    Shiny.setInputValue("choice", text);
    instance.rename_node(node, text);
  });
});
'

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(script))),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,jstreeOutput("mytree")),
    column(width = 8,verbatimTextOutput("choices"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["mytree"]] <- renderJstree(mytree)
  Choices <- reactiveVal(data.frame(choice = character(0)))
  observeEvent(input[["choice"]],{Choices(rbind(Choices(),data.frame(choice = input[["choice"]])))})
  observeEvent(input[["deletion"]], {Choices(Choices()[-input[["deletion"]], , drop = FALSE])})
  output[["choices"]] <- renderPrint({Choices()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
script <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var LETTERS = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  var Visited = {};
  $("#mytree").on("copy_node.jstree", function(e, data){
    var oldid = data.original.id;
    var visited = Object.keys(Visited);
    if(visited.indexOf(oldid) === -1){
      Visited[oldid] = 0;
    }else{
      Visited[oldid]++;
    }
    var letter = LETTERS[Visited[oldid]];
    var node = data.node;
    var id = node.id;
    var index = $("#"+id).index() + 1;
    var text = index + ". " + node.text + " " + letter;
    Shiny.setInputValue("choice", text);
    var instance = data.new_instance;
    instance.rename_node(node, text);
  });
});
'
```

Comment: Where did you learn to do all this? Base R functions have been easier for me to learn because of all the tutorials out there and the books available. This type of coding I don't know where to begin to learn, other than asking people like you for help.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 I begin to learn JavaScript with **jQuery**, which is easy to use. When I wanted to use JavaScript for a Shiny app, I googled for what I was searching and always found many answers on the web (often on StackOverflow). I slowly improved my skills by using JavaScript for my Shiny apps. I would recommend to start with **jQuery**.